# Android NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser.next()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nullpointerexception

i am making an android app that downloads an xml file and creates a view.
When i start the activity this throws me a NullPointer exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser.next()' on a null object reference

for testing reason i started loading the file from assets folder:

```
try {

        InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getApplication().getAssets().open("xml/fragment_blank.xml");

        final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
        }



        String xmlText = Files.toString(tempFile, Charsets.UTF_8);

        byte[] data = xmlText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //String layout = Base64.encodeToString(xmlText);

        return inflater.inflate(getParser(base64), container, false);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


/**
 * return XmlPullParser
 * @param xml compiled XML encoded in base64
 * @return XmlPullParser
 */
public static XmlPullParser getParser(String xml) {
    try {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(xml, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // XmlBlock block = new XmlBlock(LAYOUT.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.content.res.XmlBlock");
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(byte[].class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object block = constructor.newInstance(data);

        // XmlPullParser parser = block.newParser();
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("newParser");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (XmlPullParser) method.invoke(block);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and the layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f3e4c4" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="7dip" android:paddingLeft="7dip" android:paddingRight="7dip"
android:paddingTop="7dip">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f3e4c4" android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.bitdubai.reference_niche_wallet.bitcoin_wallet.fragments.BlankFragment">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mati" />

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            !-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="16dp" android:text="juan" />

            <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" android:text="carlos" />

            <ImageView android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6" android:src="@drawable/person1" />


        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="14dp"
            android:background="#2ae21a"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >


            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />





            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewTypeBalance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="7dip"
                android:paddingRight="7dip"
                android:paddingTop="3dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:textColor="#FF666666"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="available balance"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewBalance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="3dip"
                android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                android:textColor="#FF666666"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="mBTC     0"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please copy all the stacktrace from logcat and put it in your answer, then we can see where is exactly the problem.